# How to find the Bazel version currently in my system via command prompt code or some other ways for Tensorflow installation

Tags: tensorflow, version, bazel

In Tensorflow's official website (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) there specified the build tools bazel versions required for each version of Tensorflow.

How can i check whether i have the right version of bazel in my windows 10 system(before getting into installing the bazel)?

Do i even need to worry about this while i am setting up the Tensorflow in my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running:

```
bazel --version
```

Will tell you which version of bazel is installed (and in search `PATH`) on your system.

For ensuring use of correct / consistent version of bazel across the board, it may be helpful to use [`bazelisk`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk) as a front to bazel which also honors the [`.bazelversion`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk#how-does-bazelisk-know-which-bazel-version-to-run) file in the current dir or its parents (if present,  as it is in the tensorflow tree ; that would normally translate to, within the bazel workspace) and runs (downloads if needed) corresponding bazel.

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>bazel --version
'bazel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: That means, if (`bazel.exe`) is on the system it, is not in search `PATH` of the environment of the shell you tried to run in from.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the file `.bazelversion` in the root TensorFlow directory, it will tell you the recommended version of Bazel to build with.

The prebuilt TensorFlow `pip` package for Windows is good for most purposes, unless you are looking at modifying TensorFlow directly.  For that you do not need Bazel.